# targeting ALL inputs inside a div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to target every checkbox inside a specific div, I have a few nested ul's that all have checkboxes in them and when you check off the most parent item I want everything inside to check off too

I was trying to do something like

```
$(this).closest("li").children('input[type=checkbox]').prop("checked", true);
```

Where the this referring to the click of the checkbox. All the children nested inside the li (they are all children). I can't seem to get it to target everything inside. In short - I'm just trying to say target every single checkbox inside this div on this event (no matter how nested it is).

Comment: please demonstrate your problem in a fiddle.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use 'find'. 'Children' only looks in one level down the DOM

```
$(this).closest("li").find('input[type=checkbox]').prop("checked", true);
```

Comment: does .find traverse down the entire dom, or just inside the li? because there are other parent li's below that have the same situation that i do not want checked off. Just everything inside the current li. Thanks!

Comment: `closest("li")` will search _up_ the DOM until it finds an 'li' and then `find` will start _down_ until it finds a checkbox (so yes only within the current 'li')

Answer (score 1):

you can use `find` instead of `children`. like:

```
$(this).closest("li").find('input[type=checkbox]').prop("checked", true);
```